# Why does Minecraft say Internal Exception: io.nettty.handler?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I try to go on a multiplayer server and it says

```
Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex (9) + length (1) exceeds
writerIndex (9): UnpooledHeapByteBuf (ridx: 9, width: 9, cap: 9)
```

I use the latest update for all the servers I go on, 1.8.7 and I can go on other servers just fine. I was on the server and randomly it kicked me out saying that and I can't get back on.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I couldn't get on because I was logged into Minechat.

If you're logged into Minechat you need to make sure you disconnect before exiting out of the app, Otherwise Minecraft will think you're still logged into the server.

Comment: For the benefit of people who might have the same problem, could you tell what exactly was wrong in more detail. At the moment all I understan is that "I couldn't get on the server, because I was on the server."

Comment: You can also mark your answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark under the vote count. This will help future visitors know this answer worked for you :)